# Repeating A Function for Many Values and Building a 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a code.

It takes in a value N and does a quantum walk for that many steps and gives an array that shows the probability at each position.

It's quite a complex calculation and N must be a single integer.

What I want to do is repeat this calculation for 100 values of N and build a large 2D array.

Any idea how I would do this?

Here's my code:

```
N = 100    # number of random steps
P = 2*N+1    # number of positions
#defining a quantum coin
coin0 = array([1, 0])  # |0>
coin1 = array([0, 1])  # |1>
#defining the coin operator
C00 = outer(coin0, coin0)  # |0><0| 
C01 = outer(coin0, coin1)  # |0><1| 
C10 = outer(coin1, coin0)  # |1><0| 
C11 = outer(coin1, coin1)  # |1><1| 

C_hat = (C00 + C01 + C10 - C11)/sqrt(2.)
#step operator
ShiftPlus = roll(eye(P), 1, axis=0)
ShiftMinus = roll(eye(P), -1, axis=0)
S_hat = kron(ShiftPlus, C00) + kron(ShiftMinus, C11)
#walk operator
U = S_hat.dot(kron(eye(P), C_hat))
#defining the initial state
posn0 = zeros(P)
posn0[N] = 1     # array indexing starts from 0, so index N is the central posn
psi0 = kron(posn0,(coin0+coin1*1j)/sqrt(2.))
#the state after N steps
psiN = linalg.matrix_power(U, N).dot(psi0)
#finidng the probabilty operator
prob = empty(P)
for k in range(P):
    posn = zeros(P)
    posn[k] = 1     
    M_hat_k = kron( outer(posn,posn), eye(2))
    proj = M_hat_k.dot(psiN)
    prob[k] = proj.dot(proj.conjugate()).real

prob[prob==0] = np.nan
nanmask = np.isfinite(prob)
prob_masked=prob[nanmask] #this is the final probability to be plotted
P_masked=arange(P)[nanmask] #these are the possible positions
```

Rather than writing out the array I get as it is 100 units, this is a graph of the position and probability at N = 100

[image: position and probability at N = 100]

I eventually want to make a 3D plot of position against N against probability.

Comment: Just take all your arrays and keep pushing them into another list/array I guess. Are you talking about numpy arrays?

Comment: please show your code, and sample of your input and desired output, so we can help better.

Comment: Added my code and an image showing the output.

Comment: If you know how many values you are going to have, what you want to do is initialise an array of the right size and fill the values in as you go.